# Forkjoinpool behavior vs ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, executorservice, fork-join

We have a scenario to insert ~4M records into database. We receive these records in batches of 56 files, each containing ~80k records.

Used Forkjoinpool  to insert the records in batches of 1000.
Once all the threads are completed we proceed further.

Noticed that Forkjoinpool.get() is not blocking. It doesn't wait for the thread to complete.
This is causing some of the records to be missed(~5k) saving in the database.

Replaced Forkjoinpool with ExecutorService which works as expected. All the ~4M records are saved.

Wanted to understand why Forkjoinpool.get() is not blocking.

Both the approaches take ~5 mins to complete. Performance wise no issues.

ForkJoinpool

```
//Partition 80000 records into chunks of 1000 records
List<List<EntityObject>> entitiesPartitonList = Lists.partion(EntityObjectsList);

ForkJoinPool filesFJP= new ForkJoinPool(80);
filesFJP.submit(()->entitiesPartitonList.parallelStream().foreach(entitesBatch->{
            jdbctemplate.batchupdate(query,entitesBatch.toArray(new Map[entitesBatch.size]))
})).get();
```

ExectorService

```
List<Future<Boolean>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
ExecutorService es=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(80)

entitiesPartitonList.foreach(entitesBatch->futures.add(es.submit(()->{
        jdbctemplate.batchupdate(query,entitesBatch.toArray(new Map[entitesBatch.size]))
})));

futures.foreach(fut->fut.get());
```

Comment: (1) ForkJoinPool doesn’t have a `get` method. I think you meant ForkJoinTask.get(). (2) That get method absolutely does wait for the task to finish. Are you sure you’re submitting synchronous tasks to the ForkJoinPool? (3) A ForkJoinPool *is* an ExecutorService, so you should forget about the ForkJoinTasks returned by submit and instead call the ForkJoinPool’s shutdown() method followed by awaitTermination. You also may want to look into the invokeAll method.

Comment: Yes. I meant the task.get(). I did call the shutdown and awaitTermination in the end. But every time some of the records were lost.

Comment: By the way, consider [bulk insert](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulk_insert) to greatly improve your loading times. For example, see [this guide for Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/populate.html).

Comment: Double check you have not trapped exceptions and continued.

Comment: @DuncG Nope no exceptions.